# SBT: Is it possible to load user class in build.sbt and run it?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two projects:

```scala
lazy val project1 = (project in file("project1"))
  .settings(mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Main"))

lazy val project2 = (project in file("project2"))
  .settings(mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Main"))
```

And project1 contains `project1/src/scala/Foo.scala`

Now, I would like to run a task that use classes from project1 when compiling the project2: Something along the lines of:

```scala
  project2.settings(result := {
     val result: String = new project1.Foo().name 
     .. do something
  })
```

Is it even possible? What if I don't know the name (Foo) in advance. Can I list all classes in folder `project/src/scala/` and instantiate them all?

Comment: Is `project1.Foo` only useful for compiling `project2`? Or, do you also need it in the classpath for **runtime**.

Comment: I also need it for runtime.

Comment: And why exactly do you need it for compilation? What does it do?

Comment: I have a parser library, with high level API, which generates low-level DFA parser. I tried two approaches: generate a string (`"class ParserDFA {..}"`) and use a macro, that generates it at compile time.

Comment: Problem with macro is, that it forces the user to artificially separate its project into multiple compilation units, since macros in scala are limited.
So I am now trying the first approach: When compiling the project, first generate the string representation of ParserDFA, then save it to `target/...` folder and then later use it directly in the code.

Comment: Okey, I get it. You basically want a [**source generator**](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html). But then my first question remains. Why do you need the logic that generate the files in runtime? - I believe that you really need to segregate your project in two modules. 1. An **API _(library)_** that allows the user to call an operate the parser. 1. An **SBT Plugin** which has the generation logic. Probably from an input config file.

Comment: Then your user will need to include both, the plugin and the library _(or you can configure the plugin to include the library)_. Then, it should place in some standard path the config file to generate the parser. And in application code, it will use the **API** to call the generated parser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196205/discussion-between-ford-o-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).